# Bind textbox to listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

There is a listBox named as `listB_addRemove`. I tried to bind a textbox to that listBox but I failed and nothing has shown in textbox. Below is what I tried:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,40,0,0" Name="textBox1"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1"
         DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listB_addRemove, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the Text, not the `DataContext`:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="71,40,0,0" Name="textBox1"
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.Row="1"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=listB_addRemove, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding the `Text`, look up how the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx) works. If you keep this you need to add `Text="{Binding .}"`. Also note that if you do not bind via [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) directly in the `Text` you cannot bind two-way, so if you want that you should move the `DataContext` binding to `Text`.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is on the DataContext attribute of the TextBox and it should be on the Text attribute instead.